# Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error when setting Formula property

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This works fine:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRANSFORM")
        strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(A2:B2)"
        strFormulas(2) = "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)"
        strFormulas(3) = "=A2/B2"

        .Range("A4:G4").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("A4:G20").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

But this doesn't work - everything is the same besides `strFormulas(1)`:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRANSFORM")
        strFormulas(1) = "=IF(NOT(IMPORT!A4=''),VLOOKUP(IMPORT!A4,'VL1'!$Q$4:$R$26,2,FALSE),'-')"
        strFormulas(2) = "=PRODUCT(A2:B2)"
        strFormulas(3) = "=A2/B2"

        .Range("A4:G4").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("A4:G20").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

I get this error:

> Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

I think it may be because I'm trying to pull values from another worksheet in `strFormulas(1)`.

I did my research and couldn't find a solution. Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: You got apostrophes `'` in the `strFormulas(1)` where there should be quotation marks `"`. So, it should be more something like `"=IF(NOT(IMPORT!A4=""""),VLOOKUP(IMPO....` Just replace all `'` **within** the formula with two quotation marks `""`.

Comment: fixed! thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ralph you should post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got apostrophes `'` in the `strFormulas(1)` where there should be quotation marks `"`. So, it should be more something like

```
strFormulas(1) = "=IF(NOT(IMPORT!A4=""""),VLOOKUP(IMPORT!A4,""VL1""!$Q$4:$R$26,2,FALSE),""-"")"
```

Just replace all `'` **within** the formula with **two** quotation marks `""`.